# Replace unicode space characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I need to replace the unicode characters defined on [here](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/chars/spaces.html)

I have got this so far but it seems to remove all space including standard spacebar ones:

```
var str = "Hello this is a test  of the site"; 
str= str.replace(/[ \u00A0\u1680​\u180e\u2000-\u2009\u200a​\u200b​\u202f\u205f​\u3000]/g,'')
```

Result - Hellothisisatestofthesite

I only want to remove the unicode character which is U+2003 between 'test' and 'of' in the string.

Answer (score 23):

Remove the regular space that you have first in the pattern:

```
 str = str.replace(/[\u00A0\u1680​\u180e\u2000-\u2009\u200a​\u200b​\u202f\u205f​\u3000]/g,'');
```

Comment: @Bojangles: Space characters are like black holes; they can only be seen by how they affect other things, that are visible. :)

Comment: Very well put. I didn't notice it in the OP because it wasn't formatted as code

Comment: Thanks I completely missed that space at the beginning.

Answer (score 5):

try this:

```
var str = "Hello this is a test  of the site";
str= str.replace(/[\u00A0\u1680​\u180e\u2000-\u2009\u200a​\u200b​\u202f\u205f​\u3000]/g,'')
```

same as you did, but with out ' '  (regular space)

Answer (score 3):

I guess you should use the escape sequence for spaces (15.10.2.12 of the norm) which is \s, and that you want to replace multiple spaces by a single one :

```
str= str.replace(/\s+/g,' ') ;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can simplify, try this:

```
str = str.replace(/(?! )\s/g,'');
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/acexun/2/edit

Comment: what does this regex mean ?

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer looking to replace unusual unicode space characters (generated by OCR) in OpenRefine/GREL. Here's what I used, thanks to other answers, and it works great:

`replace(value,/[\u00A0\u1680\u180e\u2000-\u2009\u200a\u200b\u202f\u205f\u3000]/," ")`

Putting it here so it's searchable.