# regex matching a new line

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to replace all invalid characters with a blank string, but my regex is also matching newlines (which I want to keep). Does anyone know where my regex is matching a newline?

```js
var re = /[\0-\x1F\x7F-\x9F\xAD\u0378\u0379\u037F-\u0383\u038B\u038D\u03A2\u0528-\u0530\u0557\u0558\u0560\u0588\u058B-\u058E\u0590\u05C8-\u05CF\u05EB-\u05EF\u05F5-\u0605\u061C\u061D\u06DD\u070E\u070F\u074B\u074C\u07B2-\u07BF\u07FB-\u07FF\u082E\u082F\u083F\u085C\u085D\u085F-\u089F\u08A1\u08AD-\u08E3\u08FF\u0978\u0980\u0984\u098D\u098E\u0991\u0992\u09A9\u09B1\u09B3-\u09B5\u09BA\u09BB\u09C5\u09C6\u09C9\u09CA\u09CF-\u09D6\u09D8-\u09DB\u09DE\u09E4\u09E5\u09FC-\u0A00\u0A04\u0A0B-\u0A0E\u0A11\u0A12\u0A29\u0A31\u0A34\u0A37\u0A3A\u0A3B\u0A3D\u0A43-\u0A46\u0A49\u0A4A\u0A4E-\u0A50\u0A52-\u0A58\u0A5D\u0A5F-\u0A65\u0A76-\u0A80\u0A84\u0A8E\u0A92\u0AA9\u0AB1\u0AB4\u0ABA\u0ABB\u0AC6\u0ACA\u0ACE\u0ACF\u0AD1-\u0ADF\u0AE4\u0AE5\u0AF2-\u0B00\u0B04\u0B0D\u0B0E\u0B11\u0B12\u0B29\u0B31\u0B34\u0B3A\u0B3B\u0B45\u0B46\u0B49\u0B4A\u0B4E-\u0B55\u0B58-\u0B5B\u0B5E\u0B64\u0B65\u0B78-\u0B81\u0B84\u0B8B-\u0B8D\u0B91\u0B96-\u0B98\u0B9B\u0B9D\u0BA0-\u0BA2\u0BA5-\u0BA7\u0BAB-\u0BAD\u0BBA-\u0BBD\u0BC3-\u0BC5\u0BC9\u0BCE\u0BCF\u0BD1-\u0BD6\u0BD8-\u0BE5\u0BFB-\u0C00\u0C04\u0C0D\u0C11\u0C29\u0C34\u0C3A-\u0C3C\u0C45\u0C49\u0C4E-\u0C54\u0C57\u0C5A-\u0C5F\u0C64\u0C65\u0C70-\u0C77\u0C80\u0C81\u0C84\u0C8D\u0C91\u0CA9\u0CB4\u0CBA\u0CBB\u0CC5\u0CC9\u0CCE-\u0CD4\u0CD7-\u0CDD\u0CDF\u0CE4\u0CE5\u0CF0\u0CF3-\u0D01\u0D04\u0D0D\u0D11\u0D3B\u0D3C\u0D45\u0D49\u0D4F-\u0D56\u0D58-\u0D5F\u0D64\u0D65\u0D76-\u0D78\u0D80\u0D81\u0D84\u0D97-\u0D99\u0DB2\u0DBC\u0DBE\u0DBF\u0DC7-\u0DC9\u0DCB-\u0DCE\u0DD5\u0DD7\u0DE0-\u0DF1\u0DF5-\u0E00\u0E3B-\u0E3E\u0E5C-\u0E80\u0E83\u0E85\u0E86\u0E89\u0E8B\u0E8C\u0E8E-\u0E93\u0E98\u0EA0\u0EA4\u0EA6\u0EA8\u0EA9\u0EAC\u0EBA\u0EBE\u0EBF\u0EC5\u0EC7\u0ECE\u0ECF\u0EDA\u0EDB\u0EE0-\u0EFF\u0F48\u0F6D-\u0F70\u0F98\u0FBD\u0FCD\u0FDB-\u0FFF\u10C6\u10C8-\u10CC\u10CE\u10CF\u1249\u124E\u124F\u1257\u1259\u125E\u125F\u1289\u128E\u128F\u12B1\u12B6\u12B7\u12BF\u12C1\u12C6\u12C7\u12D7\u1311\u1316\u1317\u135B\u135C\u137D-\u137F\u139A-\u139F\u13F5-\u13FF\u169D-\u169F\u16F1-\u16FF\u170D\u1715-\u171F\u1737-\u173F\u1754-\u175F\u176D\u1771\u1774-\u177F\u17DE\u17DF\u17EA-\u17EF\u17FA-\u17FF\u180F\u181A-\u181F\u1878-\u187F\u18AB-\u18AF\u18F6-\u18FF\u191D-\u191F\u192C-\u192F\u193C-\u193F\u1941-\u1943\u196E\u196F\u1975-\u197F\u19AC-\u19AF\u19CA-\u19CF\u19DB-\u19DD\u1A1C\u1A1D\u1A5F\u1A7D\u1A7E\u1A8A-\u1A8F\u1A9A-\u1A9F\u1AAE-\u1AFF\u1B4C-\u1B4F\u1B7D-\u1B7F\u1BF4-\u1BFB\u1C38-\u1C3A\u1C4A-\u1C4C\u1C80-\u1CBF\u1CC8-\u1CCF\u1CF7-\u1CFF\u1DE7-\u1DFB\u1F16\u1F17\u1F1E\u1F1F\u1F46\u1F47\u1F4E\u1F4F\u1F58\u1F5A\u1F5C\u1F5E\u1F7E\u1F7F\u1FB5\u1FC5\u1FD4\u1FD5\u1FDC\u1FF0\u1FF1\u1FF5\u1FFF\u200B-\u200F\u202A-\u202E\u2060-\u206F\u2072\u2073\u208F\u209D-\u209F\u20BB-\u20CF\u20F1-\u20FF\u218A-\u218F\u23F4-\u23FF\u2427-\u243F\u244B-\u245F\u2700\u2B4D-\u2B4F\u2B5A-\u2BFF\u2C2F\u2C5F\u2CF4-\u2CF8\u2D26\u2D28-\u2D2C\u2D2E\u2D2F\u2D68-\u2D6E\u2D71-\u2D7E\u2D97-\u2D9F\u2DA7\u2DAF\u2DB7\u2DBF\u2DC7\u2DCF\u2DD7\u2DDF\u2E3C-\u2E7F\u2E9A\u2EF4-\u2EFF\u2FD6-\u2FEF\u2FFC-\u2FFF\u3040\u3097\u3098\u3100-\u3104\u312E-\u3130\u318F\u31BB-\u31BF\u31E4-\u31EF\u321F\u32FF\u4DB6-\u4DBF\u9FCD-\u9FFF\uA48D-\uA48F\uA4C7-\uA4CF\uA62C-\uA63F\uA698-\uA69E\uA6F8-\uA6FF\uA78F\uA794-\uA79F\uA7AB-\uA7F7\uA82C-\uA82F\uA83A-\uA83F\uA878-\uA87F\uA8C5-\uA8CD\uA8DA-\uA8DF\uA8FC-\uA8FF\uA954-\uA95E\uA97D-\uA97F\uA9CE\uA9DA-\uA9DD\uA9E0-\uA9FF\uAA37-\uAA3F\uAA4E\uAA4F\uAA5A\uAA5B\uAA7C-\uAA7F\uAAC3-\uAADA\uAAF7-\uAB00\uAB07\uAB08\uAB0F\uAB10\uAB17-\uAB1F\uAB27\uAB2F-\uABBF\uABEE\uABEF\uABFA-\uABFF\uD7A4-\uD7AF\uD7C7-\uD7CA\uD7FC-\uF8FF\uFA6E\uFA6F\uFADA-\uFAFF\uFB07-\uFB12\uFB18-\uFB1C\uFB37\uFB3D\uFB3F\uFB42\uFB45\uFBC2-\uFBD2\uFD40-\uFD4F\uFD90\uFD91\uFDC8-\uFDEF\uFDFE\uFDFF\uFE1A-\uFE1F\uFE27-\uFE2F\uFE53\uFE67\uFE6C-\uFE6F\uFE75\uFEFD-\uFF00\uFFBF-\uFFC1\uFFC8\uFFC9\uFFD0\uFFD1\uFFD8\uFFD9\uFFDD-\uFFDF\uFFE7\uFFEF-\uFFFB\uFFFE\uFFFF]/g;
```

Comment: What constitutes an invalid character? Or consider the opposite question: which characters are considered valid? Perhaps there is a much simpler way of expressing this by negating the regex for valid characters.

Comment: well many of the invalid characters i see give me an octal dump of \003 or \003$

Comment: Take a step back. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve that you think needs such a complex and incomprehensible regex? For example, are you just trying to remove all characters except the english alphabet and some standard punctuation and newlines?

Comment: I am trying to remove invisible invalid characters in my txt doc. if i run od -c in terminal, these characters would be represented by 003

Comment: cannot figure out what the regex would be for characters like these. Or why...

Comment: Just at the beginning.... in the segment in between `\0` and `\x1f` there are two characters: `\x0d` and `\x0a` that are being included there.  just change the beginning from `/[\0-\x1f` to `/\0-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just at the beginning.... in the segment in between `\0` and `\x1f` there are two characters: `\x0d` and `\x0a` that are being included there (those are the guilty ones).  just change the beginning from `/[\0-\x1f` to `/\0-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f` If you want also to conserve tabs, then don't include `\x09` also.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
https://regex101.com/r/nH2rY4/1
```

However, in regex101 if you go to the end of the expression and accidentally add a carriage return, it will match it.  Compare it with this:

```
https://regex101.com/r/nH2rY4/2
```

Comment: Please include the actual answer inline, rather than only linking to an external site. See the Help page on [How to write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: A proper way for this question is reading regular expression from scratch this link helps a lot...so down vote is not required

Answer (score 0):

Based on this question here (not a duplicate I think, there is no linebreak issue): [Replace unicode space characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16416610/replace-unicode-space-characters), this is a good start: `var re = /(?![ \r\n])\s/`. It'll matches all whitespace except for "real" space and new line characters. Now, you'll need to add all the accepted characters (letters, numbers, punctuation...) and negate them so anything that is not in the accepted list will match.

Answer (score 0):

Newlines and carriage returns are both included in `\0-\x1F`.

- Newline `\n` is `\x0A`.
- Carriage return `\r` is `\x0D`.

If you want to exclude them from your character class:

```
var re = /[\0-\x09\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x1F\x7F-\x9F\xAD\u0378\u0379\u037F-\u0383\u038B\u038D\u03A2\u0528-\u0530\u0557\u0558\u0560\u0588\u058B-\u058E\u0590\u05C8-\u05CF\u05EB-\u05EF\u05F5-\u0605\u061C\u061D\u06DD\u070E\u070F\u074B\u074C\u07B2-\u07BF\u07FB-\u07FF\u082E\u082F\u083F\u085C\u085D\u085F-\u089F\u08A1\u08AD-\u08E3\u08FF\u0978\u0980\u0984\u098D\u098E\u0991\u0992\u09A9\u09B1\u09B3-\u09B5\u09BA\u09BB\u09C5\u09C6\u09C9\u09CA\u09CF-\u09D6\u09D8-\u09DB\u09DE\u09E4\u09E5\u09FC-\u0A00\u0A04\u0A0B-\u0A0E\u0A11\u0A12\u0A29\u0A31\u0A34\u0A37\u0A3A\u0A3B\u0A3D\u0A43-\u0A46\u0A49\u0A4A\u0A4E-\u0A50\u0A52-\u0A58\u0A5D\u0A5F-\u0A65\u0A76-\u0A80\u0A84\u0A8E\u0A92\u0AA9\u0AB1\u0AB4\u0ABA\u0ABB\u0AC6\u0ACA\u0ACE\u0ACF\u0AD1-\u0ADF\u0AE4\u0AE5\u0AF2-\u0B00\u0B04\u0B0D\u0B0E\u0B11\u0B12\u0B29\u0B31\u0B34\u0B3A\u0B3B\u0B45\u0B46\u0B49\u0B4A\u0B4E-\u0B55\u0B58-\u0B5B\u0B5E\u0B64\u0B65\u0B78-\u0B81\u0B84\u0B8B-\u0B8D\u0B91\u0B96-\u0B98\u0B9B\u0B9D\u0BA0-\u0BA2\u0BA5-\u0BA7\u0BAB-\u0BAD\u0BBA-\u0BBD\u0BC3-\u0BC5\u0BC9\u0BCE\u0BCF\u0BD1-\u0BD6\u0BD8-\u0BE5\u0BFB-\u0C00\u0C04\u0C0D\u0C11\u0C29\u0C34\u0C3A-\u0C3C\u0C45\u0C49\u0C4E-\u0C54\u0C57\u0C5A-\u0C5F\u0C64\u0C65\u0C70-\u0C77\u0C80\u0C81\u0C84\u0C8D\u0C91\u0CA9\u0CB4\u0CBA\u0CBB\u0CC5\u0CC9\u0CCE-\u0CD4\u0CD7-\u0CDD\u0CDF\u0CE4\u0CE5\u0CF0\u0CF3-\u0D01\u0D04\u0D0D\u0D11\u0D3B\u0D3C\u0D45\u0D49\u0D4F-\u0D56\u0D58-\u0D5F\u0D64\u0D65\u0D76-\u0D78\u0D80\u0D81\u0D84\u0D97-\u0D99\u0DB2\u0DBC\u0DBE\u0DBF\u0DC7-\u0DC9\u0DCB-\u0DCE\u0DD5\u0DD7\u0DE0-\u0DF1\u0DF5-\u0E00\u0E3B-\u0E3E\u0E5C-\u0E80\u0E83\u0E85\u0E86\u0E89\u0E8B\u0E8C\u0E8E-\u0E93\u0E98\u0EA0\u0EA4\u0EA6\u0EA8\u0EA9\u0EAC\u0EBA\u0EBE\u0EBF\u0EC5\u0EC7\u0ECE\u0ECF\u0EDA\u0EDB\u0EE0-\u0EFF\u0F48\u0F6D-\u0F70\u0F98\u0FBD\u0FCD\u0FDB-\u0FFF\u10C6\u10C8-\u10CC\u10CE\u10CF\u1249\u124E\u124F\u1257\u1259\u125E\u125F\u1289\u128E\u128F\u12B1\u12B6\u12B7\u12BF\u12C1\u12C6\u12C7\u12D7\u1311\u1316\u1317\u135B\u135C\u137D-\u137F\u139A-\u139F\u13F5-\u13FF\u169D-\u169F\u16F1-\u16FF\u170D\u1715-\u171F\u1737-\u173F\u1754-\u175F\u176D\u1771\u1774-\u177F\u17DE\u17DF\u17EA-\u17EF\u17FA-\u17FF\u180F\u181A-\u181F\u1878-\u187F\u18AB-\u18AF\u18F6-\u18FF\u191D-\u191F\u192C-\u192F\u193C-\u193F\u1941-\u1943\u196E\u196F\u1975-\u197F\u19AC-\u19AF\u19CA-\u19CF\u19DB-\u19DD\u1A1C\u1A1D\u1A5F\u1A7D\u1A7E\u1A8A-\u1A8F\u1A9A-\u1A9F\u1AAE-\u1AFF\u1B4C-\u1B4F\u1B7D-\u1B7F\u1BF4-\u1BFB\u1C38-\u1C3A\u1C4A-\u1C4C\u1C80-\u1CBF\u1CC8-\u1CCF\u1CF7-\u1CFF\u1DE7-\u1DFB\u1F16\u1F17\u1F1E\u1F1F\u1F46\u1F47\u1F4E\u1F4F\u1F58\u1F5A\u1F5C\u1F5E\u1F7E\u1F7F\u1FB5\u1FC5\u1FD4\u1FD5\u1FDC\u1FF0\u1FF1\u1FF5\u1FFF\u200B-\u200F\u202A-\u202E\u2060-\u206F\u2072\u2073\u208F\u209D-\u209F\u20BB-\u20CF\u20F1-\u20FF\u218A-\u218F\u23F4-\u23FF\u2427-\u243F\u244B-\u245F\u2700\u2B4D-\u2B4F\u2B5A-\u2BFF\u2C2F\u2C5F\u2CF4-\u2CF8\u2D26\u2D28-\u2D2C\u2D2E\u2D2F\u2D68-\u2D6E\u2D71-\u2D7E\u2D97-\u2D9F\u2DA7\u2DAF\u2DB7\u2DBF\u2DC7\u2DCF\u2DD7\u2DDF\u2E3C-\u2E7F\u2E9A\u2EF4-\u2EFF\u2FD6-\u2FEF\u2FFC-\u2FFF\u3040\u3097\u3098\u3100-\u3104\u312E-\u3130\u318F\u31BB-\u31BF\u31E4-\u31EF\u321F\u32FF\u4DB6-\u4DBF\u9FCD-\u9FFF\uA48D-\uA48F\uA4C7-\uA4CF\uA62C-\uA63F\uA698-\uA69E\uA6F8-\uA6FF\uA78F\uA794-\uA79F\uA7AB-\uA7F7\uA82C-\uA82F\uA83A-\uA83F\uA878-\uA87F\uA8C5-\uA8CD\uA8DA-\uA8DF\uA8FC-\uA8FF\uA954-\uA95E\uA97D-\uA97F\uA9CE\uA9DA-\uA9DD\uA9E0-\uA9FF\uAA37-\uAA3F\uAA4E\uAA4F\uAA5A\uAA5B\uAA7C-\uAA7F\uAAC3-\uAADA\uAAF7-\uAB00\uAB07\uAB08\uAB0F\uAB10\uAB17-\uAB1F\uAB27\uAB2F-\uABBF\uABEE\uABEF\uABFA-\uABFF\uD7A4-\uD7AF\uD7C7-\uD7CA\uD7FC-\uF8FF\uFA6E\uFA6F\uFADA-\uFAFF\uFB07-\uFB12\uFB18-\uFB1C\uFB37\uFB3D\uFB3F\uFB42\uFB45\uFBC2-\uFBD2\uFD40-\uFD4F\uFD90\uFD91\uFDC8-\uFDEF\uFDFE\uFDFF\uFE1A-\uFE1F\uFE27-\uFE2F\uFE53\uFE67\uFE6C-\uFE6F\uFE75\uFEFD-\uFF00\uFFBF-\uFFC1\uFFC8\uFFC9\uFFD0\uFFD1\uFFD8\uFFD9\uFFDD-\uFFDF\uFFE7\uFFEF-\uFFFB\uFFFE\uFFFF]/g;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ^$ to  to match blank string or \s to match one line i am not sure on which language or you using i will give regualr expression in python and perl

Python

```
re.sub(r'^$','What ever you want to replace',variable)
re.sub(r'\s','What ever you want to replace',variable)
```

Perl

```
re =~ s/^$/What ever you want to replace/sg
re =~ s/\s/What ever you want to replace/sg
```