# Create a editor with contenteditable element and iframe

Tags: jquery, css, iframe

My issue currently is when I put a space into the css like this. The rule wont show

```html
body{
 background-color : red;
}
```

only if I have everything against the side will it work like this

```css
body{
background-color : red;
}
```

I am currently creating a 2 div that takes on the attribute contenteditable.

```
<div class="editor-field html-field" data-name="html" contenteditable="true"></div>
<div class="editor-field css-field" data-name="css" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

In my javascript I am setting an interval.

```
setInterval(modifyEditor, 1500);
```

This is how I put my html and css into the iframe.

```js
var iframeContent = $('iframe').contents();
setIframeCss(iframeContent);
var iframeBody = iframeContent.find('body');
var iframeCss = iframeContent.find('#editorStyles');

function modifyEditor(){

  var checkHtmlText = $('.html-field').text();
  var checkCssText = $('.css-field').text();

  if(htmlText != checkHtmlText){
    htmlText = checkHtmlText;
    iframeBody.html(htmlText);
  }

  if(cssText != checkCssText){
    cssText = checkCssText;
    iframeCss.html(cssText);
  }

}

function setIframeCss(iframeContent){
  var createStyle = $('<style class= "editorStyles" id = "editorStyles"></style>');
  iframeContent.find('head').append(createStyle);
}
```

Comment: Rulesets  are pretty flexible in my experience. It looks as if the first one is an unbroken line and the second one there are 2 lines. In short maybe the editor interprets an new line as separate and not part of a block of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In HTML, spaces are collapsed. In order to show spaces properly under various conditions (like spaces that start at the beginning of a line), the browser will instead substitute a regular space (character code 32) with a non-breaking space (character code 160). This is fine for HTML, but CSS does not understand what a non-breaking space is. It is seen as an invalid character and the whole line or block is marked invalid (it is seen as a syntax error).

### What do I do?

A simple lookup of how to replace unicode spacing characters came to this answer on StackOverflow, answer thanks to @[Guffa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/69083/guffa) :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16416631/1456201

Need to add a replace method with a regular expression involving unicode space characters (in your case the first \u00A0 would work but why not include them all to cover any possibility since this is a user input case?):

```js
str.replace(/[\u00A0\u1680​\u180e\u2000-\u2009\u200a​\u200b​\u202f\u205f​\u3000]/g,'');
```

Here is a JSFiddle with a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/jimbo2150/Lgnqabp5/1/