# Why do some strings contain "&nbsp;" and some " ", when my input is the same(" ")?

Tags: html, string, vue.js

My problem occurs when I try to use some data/strings in a p-element.

I start of with data like this:

```
data: function() {
  return {
    reportText: {
      text1: "This is some subject text",
      text2: "This is the conclusion",
    }
  }
}
```

I use this data as follows in my (vue-)html:

```
<p> {{ reportText.text1 }} </p>
<p> {{ reportText.text2 }} </p>
```

In my browser, when I inspect my elements I get to see the following results:

```
<p>This&nbsp;is&nbsp;some&nbsp;subject&nbsp;text</p>
<p>This is the conclusion</p>
```

As you can see, there is suddenly a difference, one p element uses `&nbsp;` and the other , even though I started of with both strings only using . I know `&nbsp;` and  technically represent the same thingm, but the problem with the `&nbsp;` string is that it gets treated as a string with 1 large word instead of multiple separate words. This screws up my layout and I can't solve this by using certain css properties (word-wrap etc.)

Other things I have tried:

- Tried sanitizing the strings by using .replace(`&nbsp;`, ), but that doesn't do anything. I assume this is because it basically is the same, so there is nothing to really replace. Same reason why I have to use blockcode on stackoverflow to make the destinction between `&nbsp;` and .
- Logged the data from vue to see if there is any noticeable difference, but I can't see any. If I log the data/reportText I again only see string with 's

So I have the following questions:

1. Why does this happen? I can't seem to find any logical explanation why it sometimes uses 's and sometimes uses `&nbsp;`'s, it seems random, but I am sure I am missing something.
2. Any other things I could try to follow the path my string takes, so I can see where the transformation from  to `&nbsp;` happens?

Comment: Sometimes a non-breaking space is a unicode character rather than an HTML entity, and the browser's inspector displays it as an HTML entity despite it being stored as unicode. I've run into this very same problem myself. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16416610/replace-unicode-space-characters/16416631#16416631) and see if a small modification (i.e. using `' '` as the replacement instead of `''`) fixes your problem.

Comment: This worked perfectly. I am now using {{ reportText.text1 | correctSpaces }}, where correctSpaces is a filter that uses the reportText.text1 and applies .replace(/[\\u00A0]/g. " "). I still don't understand why this is needed, but at least I can now make it work. Would you like to submit a formal answer so I can accept it, or do you want me to answer it myself?

Comment: I'll be sure to submit this as a proper answer with a more in-depth explanation as well to help alleviate any lingering confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the comments, the solution devised ended up being a simple unicode character replacement targeting the `\u00A0` unicode code point (i.e. replacing unicode non-breaking spaces with ordinary spaces):

```js
str.replace(/[\\u00A0]/g, ' ')
```

Explanation:

JavaScript typically allows the use of unicode characters in two ways: you can input the rendered character directly, or you can use a unicode code point (i.e. in the case of JavaScript, a hexadecimal code prefixed with `\u` like `\u00A0`). It has no concept of an HTML entity (i.e. a character sequence between a `&` and `;` like `&nbsp;`).

The inspector tool for some browsers, however, utilizes the HTML concept of the HTML entity and will often display unicode characters using their corresponding HTML entities where applicable. If you check the same source code in Chrome's inspector vs. Firefox's inspector (as of writing this answer, anyway), you will see that Chrome uses HTML entities while Firefox uses the rendered character result. While it's a handy feature to be able to see non-printable unicode characters in the inspector, Chrome's use of HTML entities is only a convenience feature, not a reflection of the actual contents of your source code.

With that in mind, we can infer that your source code contains unicode characters in their fully rendered form. Regardless of the form of your unicode character, the fix is identical: you need to target these unicode space characters explicitly and replace them with ordinary spaces.